# How to use dependency injection with constructor parameter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject

What is the right approach to use dependency injection when I want to also pass in a parameter to the constructor of a class?

For example, here I want an IApplicationService to be injected, but I also want to pass in an application id:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel
{
    private readonly IApplicationService _applicationService;

    private readonly int _applicationId;

    public ApplicationViewModel(IApplicationService applicationService, int applicationId)
    {
        _applicationService = applicationService;
        _applicationId = applicationId;
    }
}
```

Currently, I'm using constructor injection on the controller and passing this on:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly IApplicationService _applicationService;

    public HomeController(IApplicationService applicationService)
    {
        _applicationService = applicationService;
    }

    public ActionResult Application(int applicationId)
    {
        return View(new ApplicationViewModel(_applicationService, applicationId));
    }
}
```

This works, but seems a bit ugly. The controller could have lots of action methods, each of which could require lots of services. The controller would end up getting a whole bunch of stuff injected that would mostly not be used. Also, I would rather be able to change what the view model needs injected without changing the controller.

I also tried using property injection on the view model, but it didn't work in MVC5 and property injection appears to be generally regarded as a Bad Idea™.

I'm sure the problem is that I'm not structuring the code properly. Any ideas?

Comment: Typically in MVC, the controller would construct the view model (possible via a service), and thus the view model would not need dependencies. The view model in that case would simply contain data for the view to display. Is there a reason why you are doing it differently?

Comment: There is one issue with this approach. Your model binder will also likely need to create an instance of your `ViewModel`. In that case, you would need a custom model binder that can inject your dependencies. As @YacoubMassad stated, it is better if your model contains only state (and meta-data) with *no behavior* so it doesn't need dependencies.

Comment: The `ApplicationViewModel` appears to me as runtime data. Runtime data should typically not be any part of the object graph. Full blog on this subject can be found [here](https://cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=99)

Comment: Thanks for your comments - you are all quite correct. I've moved the logic out of the view model and made it just a dumb container. Solves the problem and follows the MVC pattern much better now. Not sure what to do with this question now...